# Merge nonzero blocks of huge (sparse) file A into huge file B

Tags: files, binary, large-files

I have two partial disk images from a failing hard drive.  File B contains the bulk of the disk's contents, with gaps where sector reads failed.  File A is the result of telling [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) to retry all the failed sectors, so it is almost entirely gaps, but contains a few places where rereads succeeded.  I now need to merge the interesting contents of File A back into File B.  The algorithm is simple:

```
while not eof(A):
   read 512 bytes from A
   if any of them are nonzero:
       seek to corresponding offset in B
       write bytes into B
```

and I *could* sit down and write this myself, but I would first like to know if someone else has already written and debugged it.

(To complicate matters, due to limited space, File B and File A are on two different computers -- this is why I didn't just tell `ddrescue` to attempt to fill in the gaps in B in the first place -- but A can be transferred over the network relatively easily, being sparse.)

Comment: I don't really get why you used two computers, merging afterwards won't make it use any less space, ...?

Comment: @frostschutz One computer has enough disk space to accommodate a complete (500GB) disk image, but (for reasons too tedious to get into here) cannot be persuaded to communicate with USB-to-SATA adapters.  The other computer can talk to USB-to-SATA adapters just fine, but only has enough space for half the disk image at a time.  (In retrospect, we probably could've come up with a better plan for this operation, but having sunk nearly a month of I/O time into it, I'm not bloody starting over.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your algorithm is implemented in GNU `dd`.

```
dd bs=512 if=A of=B conv=sparse,notrunc
```

Please verify this beforehand with some test files of your choice. You don't want to inadvertently damage your File `B`. A better algorithm would be to check whether `B` also has zeroes at that position, alas that's something `dd` does not do.

As for two different computers, you have several options. Use a network filesystem that supports seeks on writes (not all do); transfer the file beforehand; or pipe through SSH like so:

```
dd if=A | ssh -C B-host dd of=B conv=sparse,notrunc
# or the other way around
ssh -C A-host dd if=A | dd of=B conv=sparse,notrunc
```

The `ssh -C` option enables compression, you'd be transferring gigabytes of zeroes over the network otherwise.

Comment: I'd suggest netcat over ssh. I'm guessing that a machine that can't talk to a USB drive probably also can't run AES or even blowfish at line rate.

Comment: @derobert I don't think network was the main issue, but there are countless ways... File `B` could be exported as a network block device (`nbd`) as well. If you're fine with network traffic being unencrypted.

Comment: Well, this is the kind of thing I'd do over a direct gigabit cross-connect, so I'd be OK with that being unencrypted. But yeah, plenty of ways to do it. But you probably want to mention one of them, especially since you mention `gzip`/vs. `ssh -C`

Comment: @derobert, actually I tested it just now out of curiosity, and `ssh -C` works fine for the purpose, so I removed the `gzip` reference to avoid confusion. The `ssh` method is the one I mentioned as I believe it's the most readily available; you're free to pick any other.